# Could we have ActionFilter extends Enum<T> asp core2

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, action-filter, custom-action-filter, asp.net-core-mvc-2.1

I am new to Asp Core, and I tried to implement an `IActionFilter` that extends an Enum Type

```
public class IndexFilter<T> : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
          // for example T.GetType.GetProperties
    }
}
```

And in the controller

```
public class CategoryController : Controller
{
    [Route("")]
    [HttpGet]
    [ServiceFilter( typeof( IndexFilter<Category> ))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    { 
          //  Code
    }
    ....
}
```

I gave it a shot and I stumbled over an Exception

```
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'AuthWebApi.Filters.IndexFilter`1[AuthWebApi.Models.Entities.Category]' has been registered.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
```

I tried to change Startup.cs to :

```
services.AddScoped<IndexFilter<CategoryParent>>();
services.AddScoped<IndexFilter<Object>>();
services.AddScoped<IndexFilter<>>();
```

and nothing worked, unless I set IndexFilter to match the Controller:

```
services.AddScoped<IndexFilter<Category>>();
```

Which makes the Enumerable class acts like a normal class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could register `IndexFilter<T>` with generic type like below:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IndexFilter<>));
```

Then, it will be able to resolve the service:

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(IndexFilter<Category>))]
public async Task<IActionResult> Category()
{
    return Ok();
}
[ServiceFilter(typeof(IndexFilter<CategoryParent>))]
public async Task<IActionResult> CategoryParent()
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Changing AddScoped function resolved the exception. In the beginning I tried copying it using my eyesight and it didn't work; And Ctrl+c -> Ctrl-v fixed it..   Thank you

Comment: @AbdulKarim If it resolved your issue, would you mind accepting it as answer?

Comment: @AbdulKarim Check [https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)